# NullPointerException DrawerLayout in TabbedActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have an app with 3 swipe tabs. So I first created the mainActivity then the 3 fragments.

I'm trying to implement a navigationdrawer in my tabbedactivity, but I'm getting an error "NullPointerException" when I try to retrieve my DrawerLayout..

I'm doing all the code on the main activity, is like that I should do, isn't it ? Or i need to create the navigation drawer in each fragment ?

Here's my mainactivity xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.dasilvadd.students.OngletCours">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/menu_navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

And in my mainActivity :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_onglet_cours);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    //récuperation des differents types de variables pour le menu de navigation
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close);

    //j'ajoute a mon DrawerLayout et je synchronise
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToogle);
    mToogle.syncState();

         //je récupère le menu de navigation
    NavigationView navigation = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.menu_navigation);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    setTitle("Mes cours");

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


    //ce Listener permet de detecter quel item a été choisi dans mon menu
    navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId())
            {   //si c'est "Mes cours" qui a été choisi
                case R.id.mes_cours:
                    //redirection vers la page "mes cours"
                    Intent cours = new Intent(OngletCours.this,MesCours.class);
                    startActivity(cours);
                    return true;
                //actions a faire si "mes branches" a été choisi
                case R.id.mes_branches:
                    Intent branche = new Intent(OngletCours.this,MesBranches.class);
                    branche.putExtra("ajouter","cours");
                    startActivity(branche);
                    return true;
                case R.id.mes_jalons:
                    Intent jalons = new Intent(OngletCours.this,PageiTude.class);
                    startActivity(jalons);
            }
            return true;

        }
    });
```

@update - log error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                at com.example.dasilvadd.students.OngletCours.onCreate(OngletCours.java:61)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can you explain me the error ? I hope it's not a dumb error... Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** You are trying to get reference of wrong `DrawerLayout` id `drawerLayout2`

**2.** Add `ActionBarDrawerToggle` listener.

**Try this:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_onglet_cours);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    mToogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    };

    ..............
    .....................
}
```

Comment: Actually, it says null when I do that line, how's that possible ?

Comment: are you still getting NullPointerException? If yes, then post your error logs

Comment: i updated my question check the log error

Comment: In OngletCours.java, what is in line 61?

Comment: this one :         mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToogle);

Comment: try my updated answer

Comment: there is not <Toolbar> in your layout xml. add toolbar first

Comment: It shows my navigationDrawer, but it doesn't open or close when I click on it..

Comment: you have to add listener. Check updated answer

Comment: it still doens't open, don't i have to add some code inside of those methods ?

Comment: Hhave you found something ?

Comment: use getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); after setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: can u check my code ? i updated it , and i still can't open or close anything.. my 3dots menu at the right doesn't work as well..

Comment: you did not added drawer toggle listener. follow my answer properly

Comment: post an image of your current status